# Error status: 404 returned with PUT request using Node.js (express), Angular, and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm really stuck trying to figure out how to update my data("Post") to MongoDB (I'm using Mongoose, MongoDB, Node, Express, and Angular 9.1.1). I have no trouble with POST and DELETE, but can't figure out where I'm going wrong with PUT.

Thanks in advance, all help really appreciated -Geoff

ANGULAR: file post.ts

```
export class Post {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    message: string;
 }
```

ANGULAR: file postsService.ts

```
//Working OK
deletePost(postId: string) {
    this.http.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${postId}`)
        .subscribe(() => {
            const updatedPosts = this.posts.filter(post => post.id !== postId);
            this.posts = updatedPosts;
            this.postsUpdate$.next([...this.posts]);
        });
    }

//Not working - I want to update one post
updatePost(postId: string, postTitle: string, postMessage: string) {
    const post: Post = { id: postId, title: postTitle, message: postMessage };
    this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${postId}`, post)
        .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
    }
```

NODE SERVER: File backend/app.js

```
// Working OK
app.delete("/api/posts/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then((result) => {
        console.log(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json({ msg: "Post deleted successfully!" });
    });
});

//Not working - I want to update one post
// Post is defined in file: backend/model/post.js
app.put("/api/post/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    const post1 = new Post({
        _id: req.body.id,
        title: req.body.title,
        message: req.body.message,
    });
Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id } ,post1)
    .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "Updated successfully!" });
    });
});
```

NODE: backend/model/post.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//note "String is a class used in node/mongoDB"
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    message: { type: String, required: true },
});
// this will automaticly be stored in collection "posts"
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

ERROR IN BROWSER:

```
// HEADERS:
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/api/posts/5ef676c71105924a08b9e919
Request Method:PUT
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Status Code:
404
Version:HTTP/1.1
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

// REQUEST:
 
Request Payload:
{"id":"5ef676c71105924a08b9e919", "title":"first Post ", "message":"This is just some text"}

// RESPONCE:
Cannot PUT /api/posts/5ef676c71105924a08b9e919
```

BUT AT URL ALL IS FINE ON GET:

```
{"msg":"Post fetched successfully!","posts":{"_id":"5ef676c71105924a08b9e919","title":"first Post ","message":"This is just some text","__v":0}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your api put request is targeting the wrong url
angular

```
this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${postId}`, post)
```

backend

```
app.put("/api/post/:id", (req, res, next) => {
```

one is post the other its posts. they need to be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much - that was it - note to me, don't program tired ;)

Comment: you are most welcome. With stuff like that its almost always a typo that you cant see cause you know whats SHOULD be there so you don't see whats IS there. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to update one post's Record so you can simply try this

```
router.put('/api/post/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    return Post.updateOne({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, {
            $set: {
                title: req.body.title,
                message: req.body.message
            }
        })
        .then(result => res.json(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

There is no need to create a new Post because you are trying to update an existing record based on the `id` and also you are sending routs path like `api/post` but you are getting a response from the server `api/posts` so check your route path as well.

Comment: It was the mismatched paths. Thanks for showing the full code with error handling. I will try it